# Getting Google directionsService.route markers

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have an array of longlats (waypoints), source and destination.

I have called the method directionsService.route and displayed the route on the map successfully. I need to get the references of all the marker objects present on the map. Is there any way i can achieve this? Like map.getMarkers returning an array of markers on the map?

Answer (score 0):

sorry it's not possible by map object but you can store the marker into the array variable

```
var allMarkers = [];
....
// Create some markers
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({...});
    allMarkers.push(marker);
}
```